# Sending commands to PIC

Tags: c, pic, mplab

First my PIC is 16f1625 and I use MPLAB 8.86 for programming it. 
My problem is simple, I have communicating between PC and PIC,PC sends one byte and PIC reads this byte, and do something.
My problem is that I would like to improve this for like this, PC send one letter like "R" and after he send the number that I'd like to set. Today i only have 4 possibility, PC send 0,1,2 or 5 and I set the resolution according to these.

```
switch(i)    {
    case 1:
        pulsesPerMm = 10;
        break;
    case 2:
        pulsesPerMm = 20;
        break;
    case 5:
        pulsesPerMm = 51;
        break;
    case 10:
        pulsesPerMm = 102;

        break;
}
```

I receive the command like these:

```
while(!RCIF)    /* set when register is not empty */
    continue;
return RCREG;
```

Now I want to do something like this: I receive "R" that indicates that the next word will be resolution and after these, 2 bytes, that will be the new resolution and i will only have to do is convert the string into int (using atoi) and then i can set the pulsesPerMm.
The problem is that I have other commands that only requires one letter, so I don't want to change these.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on rx chars instead of numbers then, in your 'R' case block only, call the getChar() function to return the next two chars and atoi() them.

Comment: I don't understand. When PC transmits the data, it only send i don know when it is, and it will send in series without break so I think i don't have time to identify the byte as 'R'.